# Error ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server en conexion de SQL Server con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server

Estoy tratando de conectar con SQL Server en una aplicación de Laravel pero me sale el siguiente error

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP
>   Provider: No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de
>   destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión. (SQL: select top 1 * from
>   [IGNom_Trabajador])

Asi tengo configurado mi archivo `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=USER\SQLEXPRESS
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=NOMDB
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

Es la primera vez que uso SQL Server y no se si estoy conectando bien con el servidor o base de datos, ¿Como puedo solucionar este error?

Comment: `el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión` = Te falta configurar cosas en el servidor. Puede ser un firewall, puede ser un antivirus, puede ser la configuración de conexión remota para MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel busca la ruta del host, puede ser que tu base de datos la tengas en tu misma Pc o en otra, prueba cambiar

```
DB_HOST=USER\SQLEXPRESS
```

por

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

ó

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

y si estas utilizando la base de datos desde otra PC, trata de usar la ip

```
DB_HOST=192.168.0.15
```

por ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que el puerto para la instancia de SQL corresponda al puerto 1433, puede que el puerto se ocupó en algún momento y este cambio.

[image: Imagen configuración de puerto]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente tengas deshabilitado tu protocolo de red TCP/IP. Prueba habilitando el servicio TCP/IP en tu servidor SQL.
Te dejo un link para apoyarte. [Deshabilitar un protocolo de red en un servidor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Si estas en local lo mas probable es que tengas que quitar el puerto y dejarlo vacío o null en `.env` y la configuración de la conexión en laravel, ya que si usas SQL Express (mas que nada en pruebas y eso) lo mas probable es que hayas configurado el servidor sin un puerto correspondiente.

Luego probar con localhost\SQLEXPRESS.

Si no checkea bien la configuración TCP/IP para habilitarla.

También el Firewall para quitar las restricciones al puerto `1433` (que es el normalmente asignado en sql server).

También no te olvides de reiniciar la conexión a la base de datos o la maquina para que los cambios impacten.